# How neural net extract features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm new on neural networks. I follow some tutorials on a lot of platforms, but there is one thing than I don't understand.

In a simple multi layer perceptron :
We have the input layer, an hidden layer for this example (with the same number of neurons than the input layer) and an output layer with one unit.

We initialize the weights of the units in hidden layer randomly but in a range of small values.
Now, the input layer is fully connected with the hidden layer.
So each units in hidden layer are going to receive the same parameters. How are they going to extract different features from each other ?

Thanks for explanation!

Comment: When using backpropagation, the symmetry of the nodes is broken (because of the random-init) and they obtain different gradients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But, what I don't get is : The random range for init seems to be very small in the different papers I read. (0 to 0,05)
Is it really enough to break the symmetry ?
And is there a risk than the backpropagation make 2 or more units weights going to be symmetrical again ? 
Thanks again!

Comment: That's enough, but is always dependent on your data and architecture. It's a tuning-parameter. Look into backprop to understand the probability of recreating symmetry. Maybe two weight will share their weights at some time, but then they are again very likely to change in the future.

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much! It's been very helpful! I'm going to check for the backprop probability! :)
Thanks again and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We initialize the weights of the units in hidden layer randomly but in
>   a range of small values. Now, the input layer is fully connected with
>   the hidden layer. So each units in hidden layer are going to receive
>   the same parameters. How are they going to extract different features
>   from each other ?

Actually each neuron will not have the same value.  To get to the activations of the hidden layer you use the matrix equation `Wx + b`  In this case W is the weight matrix of shape (Hidden Size, Input Size).  x is the input vector of the hidden layer of shape (Input Size) and b is the bias of shape (Hidden Size).  This results in an activation of shape (Hidden Size).  So while each hidden neuron would be "seeing" the same x vector it will be taking the dot product of x with its own random row vector and adding its own random bias which will give that neuron a different value.  The values contained in the W matrix and b vector are what are trained and optimized.  Since they have different starting points they will eventually learn different features through the gradient decent.

Comment: Hi!
So, the bias is changing too ? I always thought than it was remaining to 1 according to what I read..
If the bias is going to change, why not initialize it to 0 instead of 1 ? If it change, it's not matter than in the first iteration, the bias == 0 no ?
I guess this is the backprop who change it too ?
(And since I'm using Keras, I don't have to play with the bias because it's hidden to concentrate on the model..)

Comment: There is not much point in having a bias if it does not change.  However it can be constant initialized since the weight matrix is random.  You just need something to break symmetry.

Comment: Thanks!
Just a last question.. So, it doesn't matter if the init value of the bias is 1 or 0 or randomized ?
Because in all examples, it's initialized to 1. Is there a reason to that ?

Comment: From a theoretical standpoint no.  Initialization do matter practically since they can effect the speed / ability to train.  Say you made the bias 1000 and used a sigmoid activation.  This would saturate all of the activations to one regardless of the inputs and would force the gradient very close to zero.   With limited precision of floating point numbers this may never optimize.  Look at the weight initialization section.  http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

Comment: That's really great ! Thanks again!